# Short-time Fourier transform of $f\ast g (y)- f\ast g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f, g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$.  Then the convolution of two Schwartz class function is again Schwartz class  function, that is, $f\ast g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R).$

It is also known that the Fourier transform takes  convolution to point wise multiplication.

Now we define

$$H(x,y)= \int_{x}^{y} \frac{d}{dt}(f\ast g)(t) dt = f\ast g (y)- f\ast g(x),  \ (x, y \in \mathbb R)$$

We may, formally,  notice 
$$\widehat{H}(\xi, \eta)= \hat{K}(\xi) \hat{h}(\xi) \delta_0(\eta)- \hat{K}(\eta) \hat{h}(\eta) \delta_0(\xi),$$
may not be integrable.

I'm interested in the the short-time Fourier transform   of $G$ with respect to some $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^2),$ that is,
\begin{eqnarray*}
V_{\phi}H(\bar{x}, \bar{w}) & = & \int_{\mathbb R^{2}}  H(t)\phi(t-\bar{x}) e^{-2\pi i \bar{w}\cdot t} 
 dt,  \ \    (\bar{x}, \bar{y} \in \mathbb R^2).
 \end{eqnarray*}

> My Question are: (I) Is there any way to compute $V_{\phi} H$? (2) Can we expect $ \left\|\|V_{\phi}G(\bar{x}, \bar{w})\|_{L^{\infty}_{\bar{x}}(\mathbb R^2)}\right\|_{L^{1}_{\bar{w}}(\mathbb R^2)} < \infty$?

Comment: You are looking at $H \ast (\phi e^{-2i \pi w.})$. For its $L^\infty$ norm you can try with $\phi(x,y) =\sum_{l \le N,m \le N} c_{l,m}\Phi_l(x)\Phi_m(y)$

Comment: @reuns: Thanks. Can you explain a bit more? (So far from you comment I'm just getting the sense that choosing $\phi (x,y)$ in terms of two  separate variable functions, say $\Phi(x)\Phi(y)$, might help. I'm yet wondering   the motivation  behind  considering the sum? I'm curious to know). Thanks.

Comment: Take $\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2) \in S$ such that $\rho = \phi / (\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2))\in S$ then $\phi(x) =  \iint \hat{\rho}(\xi) \psi(x_1) e^{2i \pi \xi_1 x_1}\psi(x_2) e^{2i \pi \xi_2 x_2}d\xi$

Comment: @reuns: Thanks. I've formally plug in the value of $\phi$ in terms of integral you have suggested in $V_{\phi}H$. But I'm unable to see how does this choice of $\phi$ helps? Please can you explain a bit more? Thanks.